# Does VBScript have a substring() function?

Tags: string, vbscript

Is there a `substring()` function in VBScript similar to Java's `string.substring()`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Yes, `Mid`.

```
Dim sub_str
sub_str = Mid(source_str, 10, 5)
```

The first parameter is the source string, the second is the start index, and the third is the length.

@bobobobo: Note that VBScript strings are 1-based, not 0-based. Passing 0 as an argument to `Mid` results in "invalid procedure call or argument Mid".

Comment: FYI - The third parameter is optional, in which case it will return to the end of the string.

Comment: There are also Left() and Right() functions which substring from the left or the right, respectively.  I don't know if they would have performance benefits over Mid() or not.

Answer (score 13):

As [Tmdean correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223287/vbscript-substring/2223311#2223311) you can use the [`Mid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(VS.85).aspx) function. The MSDN Library also has a great reference section on VBScript which you can find here:

> [VBScript Language Reference (MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(VS.85).aspx)